# Get mime and ext from base64 image

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have next code:

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(image, 'base64');
const { ext, mime } = await FileType.fromBuffer(buffer);
```

But it fails with next error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'ext' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined.
```

Image is just JPG file, which I can easy open in photo editor. But for some reason FileType can't parse it, so question is why?

Answer (score 1):

You could have included that `undefined` means no match, but I had to look it up [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type/blob/362ac8e15409560af67a6d2c61f1ee63f0bd49e2/core.d.ts#L293) instead assuming this is indeed the package you are using.

```js
    @param buffer - A buffer representing file data. It works best if the buffer contains the entire file, it may work with a smaller portion as well.
    @returns The detected file type and MIME type, or `undefined` when there is no match.
    */
    function fromBuffer(buffer: Buffer | Uint8Array | ArrayBuffer): Promise<core.FileTypeResult | undefined>;
```

Have a look at the file that you create the buffer from with some sort of hex reader or heck, just have a look at the buffer you make in debug, does it start with the common signature for jpeg files? [find them here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

Answer (score -1):

If you're using async-await and if the awaiting promise gets rejected then an error is thrown, are you wrapping your await call in a try-catch?

The result object is undefined and hence throws an error when accessing "ext" on it.

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(image, 'base64');
try{
  const result = await FileType.fromBuffer(buffer);
  const { ext, mime } = result;
}catch(err){
  console.log('something is wrong'):
}
```

Comment: I am not asking about error handle, I am asking why FileType can't parse image

Comment: Yep, I am wrong for this context, It's impossible to find the actual reason otherwise from the given information, Sorry.